# How to update data in a SQLite database with an AND condition?

Tags: android, sqlite

this method is running successful.

```
db.update(SSFormat_One, contentValues, "hhid=" + hhid_id , null);
```

but i want to update data with and condition. i am trying this method but it's giving me error.

```
db.update(SSFormat_One, contentValues, "hhid=" + hhid_id and "respid=" + resp_id , null);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error, you are seeing,

Comment: Happy to help you @Waseem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can write in two ways :

```
long id = db.update(tableName, contentValues, "hhid=" + " = ? AND " + "respid=" + " = ?",new String[]{hhid_id, resp_id});
```

OR

```
db.update(SSFormat_One, contentValues, "hhid=" + hhid_id + " and respid=" + resp_id , null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
db.update(SSFormat_One, contentValues, "hhid=" + hhid_id + 
        " and respid=" + resp_id , null);
```

`and` is part of sql query(sqlite keyword) instead of java variable or keyword